# Dart - Is it possible to prevent implementation of method that is not in interface

Tags: dart

Is it possible to prevent implementation of method that is not in interface, for example:

```
abstract class IController {

void add();

}

class Controller implements IController {

@override
void add();

// Should not allow this, 
// methods that is not present in the interface
void addMore();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible.

An interface is a contract. If you satisfy the contract, you're allowed to implement the interface. Any code which expects something implementing the interface can use your code because it is *compatible* with the interface.

You can have any other members, there is no functionality to prevent that.
You won't be able to *call* those other members when all you know about the object is that it implements `IController` (when that's the type of the variable the value is stored in).

Why do you want to prevent subclasses from adding their own members?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it. But there's a hack to achieve that.

```
abstract class IController {
  factory IController() {
    return _Controller();
  }
  
void add();
}

class _Controller implements IController {  

  @override
  void add() {}

  void addMore() {}
}
```

Putting those two classes alone in the same file, only `IController` will have access to `_Controller` because we turned it in a `private class` using `_` so now, with the `factory` constructor inside `IController`, you can call it whenever you like and will only have access to the interface `IController` and its methods.

Comment: Will the analyzer show an error when I add a new method to the class I implement the Interface?